# Rails 3 Passing In Options Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Avi Tzurel wrote this helper for a better simple_format:

```
  def simple_format_no_tags(text, html_options = {}, options = {})
    text = '' if text.nil?
    text = smart_truncate(text, options[:truncate]) if options[:truncate].present?
    text = sanitize(text) unless options[:sanitize] == false
    text = text.to_str
    text.gsub!(/\r\n?/, "\n")                    # \r\n and \r -> \n
    text.gsub!(/([^\n]\n)(?=[^\n])/, '\1<br />') # 1 newline   -> br
    text.html_safe
  end
```

In my view I have this:

```
<%= simple_format_no_tags(article.text) %>
```

I'm new to programming and rails - what is the syntax for passing the option to truncate 144 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
simple_format_no_tags(article.text,{},{:truncate => 144})
```

`simple_format_no_tags` method looks at `options` parameter for `truncate` key. Since options is the third parameter, you will have to pass empty hash or nil for the second if you don't have any html options to pass in.

Found this implementation [here](https://github.com/dblock/artsy-feathers/blob/master/examples/smart_truncate.rb). See if this will work for you

```
def smart_truncate(text, char_limit)
  size = 0
  text.split.reject do |token|
    size += (token.size + 1)
    size > char_limit
  end.join(" ") + (text.size >= char_limit ? " ..." : "" )
end
```

Comment: I tried that but getting undefined method `smart_truncate'

Comment: I assumed that you also copied `smart_truncate` from wherever you copied `simple_format_no_tags`

Comment: great. that works! I can't seem to find how to add "read more" and have it inline with the end of the truncate. If I open a new erb tag with link_to read more it goes to the next line.